# how to replace special characters in large text file in shell scripting

Tags: scripting

I have using for below command
but I have replaced special characters some characters is replaced some one not replaced that is my equation.

```
sed "s/\,/\&\#44\;/g" VENKAT.TXT|sed "s/DÃ©cor/D\&eacute\;cor/g"
```

Comment: First of all, you can use the `-e` parameter for multiple independent replacements using `sed`.

Comment: secondly, you can run multiple sed commands in a single sed script by separating each command with semi-colons (and optional whitespace to improve readability) or newlines.

Answer (score 1):

there are two problems here, one is finding proper terminal setting. I suggest using UTF-8.

next try

```
sed -e 's:\,:\&#44;:' -e 's/Décor/D\&eacute;cor/' VENKAT.TXT
```

- you can use multiple replacement using `-e ... -e ...`
- you can use any char as separator for find and replace, not just `/`

Comment: Thanks for imformnation but first string is replaced in all occurances second string not replacing to all occrences please help me?

Comment: those substitue will remplacé FIRST occurrence of pattern in EVERY line. Can you edit the post to show a sample of original file ?

Comment: Actually I have taking two strings first string is , to &#44; And second one is DÃ©cor to D&eacute;cor but I have replaced two strings in txt file first string is replaced in all occurances second string is not placed in txt so i need to how to replace the second string in all occurances?

Comment: Actually I have taking two strings first string is , to &#44; And second one is DÃ©cor to D&eacute;cor but I have replaced two strings in txt file first string is replaced in all occurances second string is not placed in txt so i need to how to replace the second string in all occurances in at a time first string and second string in txt file after replacing two strings in txt file i how convert the csv file in automatically with help of shell scripting for below command.
ex:sed -e 's:\,:\&#44;:' -e 's/DÃ©cor/D\&:eacute\;:cor/g' VENKAT.TXT >ram.csv